# Gridview column count always 0 at startup

Tags: c#, multithreading, gridview, radgrid

The code below at my application start-up it is called. The datasource does have 1 item. However the messagebox is never shown. Now when the user interface is drawn for the first time the gridview does indeed have one row. If i call the code again on a button press the messagebox is shown correctly. What is going on here  and how can i fix it (I assume it has something to do with threading as the radGridview has not actually been updated yet)?

**C# Code to Bind Grid**

```
// Bind list to gridview
this.radGridViewFiles.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = null));
this.radGridViewFiles.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add").ToList()))); //

if (radGridViewFiles.Columns.Count > 0)
{
   RadMessageBox.Show(" This messagebox should show on startup but it does not - But if i call all this code again manually on a button press it does show ??? !!");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding GridView asynchronously, that's why when you check the Column count it's still zero.

I suggest you bind it in the same thread or wait for async operation to finish.

As you requested, here is code example using `EndInvoke`. Although if you put it like this all in one method - you will not gain anything from async calls.

```
// You don't need this, so i commented it out.
// it's excessive, you are going to overwrite this variable anyway
// this.radGridViewFiles.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = null));

var asyncRes = this.radGridViewFiles.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.Concat(MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(i => i.sItemRequestStatus == "Add").ToList())));

// This method blocks until previous operation is done
// It's quite pointless. In real life you should call it somewhere from another thread
// While qui thread is unblocked and displaying progress bar or something like this. 
this.radGridViewFiles.EndInvoke(asyncRes);

// at this point, binding is complete
if (radGridViewFiles.Columns.Count > 0)
{
   RadMessageBox.Show(" This messagebox should show on startup but it does not - But if i call all this code again manually on a button press it does show ??? !!");
}
```

Comment: how do i wait for async operation to finish ?

Comment: @user1438082 you call `EndInvoke` on your `radGridViewFiles`. This call will block until operation is done.

Comment: is that the right way to do it - I have, based on your feedback read about Async and Await and no website mentions endinvoke ? if i do need endinvoke then can you specify exactly the line / lines of code needed.

Comment: It's one of the ways to do it. It it right or wrong is hard to tell out of context. First of all i would question the need to run your binding in async manner at startup. If you do truly need it. If you call `EndInvoke` right after BeginInvoke, in the same method it will be the same result in terms of user experience - gui thread will be blocked(assuming you do that calls from gui thread)